# first row for non-aggregate functions

Tags: r, plyr

I use ddply to avoid redundant calculations.

I am often dealing with values that are conserved within the split subsets, and doing non-aggregate analysis. So to avoid this (a toy example):

```
ddply(baseball,.(id,year),function(x){paste(x$id,x$year,sep="_")})

Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels")) : 
  Results do not have equal lengths
```

I have to take the first row of each mini data frame.

```
ddply(baseball,function(x){paste(x$id[1],x$year[1],sep="_")})
```

Is there a different approach or a helper I should be using? This syntax seems awkward.

--

Note: paste in my example is just for show - don't take it too literally. Imagine this is actual function:

```
ddply(baseball,function(x){the_slowest_function_ever(x$id[1],x$year[1])})
```

Comment: i am surprised there is not a way to access the .variables from inside the function

Comment: raised issue: https://github.com/hadley/plyr/issues/68

Answer (score 3):

You might find [data.table](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) a little easier and faster in this case. The equivalent of `.()` variables is `by=` :

```
DT[, { paste(id,year,sep="_") }, by=list(id,year) ]
```

or

```
DT[, { do.call("paste",.BY) }, by=list(id,year) ]
```

I've shown the `{}` to illustrate you can put any (multi-line) anonymous body in `j` (rather than a function), but in these simple examples you don't need the `{}`.

The grouping variables are length 1 inside the scope of each group (which seems to be what you're asking), for speed and convenience. `.BY` contains the grouping variables in one list object as well, for generic access when the `by` criteria is decided programatically on the fly; i.e., when you don't know the `by` variables in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
ddply(baseball, .(id, year), function(x){data.frame(paste(x$id,x$year,sep="_"))})
```

When you return a vector, putting it back together as a data.frame makes each entry a column.  But there are different lengths, so they don't all have the same number of columns.  By wrapping it in `data.frame()`, you make sure that your function returns a `data.frame` that has the column you want rather than relying on the implicit (and in this case, wrong) transformation.  Also, you can name the new column easily within this construct.

UPDATE:

Given you only want to evaluate the function once (which is reasonable), then you can just pull the first row out by itself and operate on that.

```
ddply(baseball, .(id, year), function(x) {
  x <- x[1,]
  paste(x$id, x$year, sep="_")
})
```

This will (by itself) have only a single row for each id/year combo.  If you want it to have the same number of rows as the original, then you can combine this with the previous idea.

```
ddply(baseball, .(id, year), function(x) {
  firstrow <- x[1,]
  data.frame(label=rep(paste(firstrow$id, firstrow$year, sep="_"), nrow(x)))
})
```